# How to apply CSS to namespace prefixed elements in IE8?

Tags: css, xml, namespaces

http://mailmarkup.org/hcl/hcl1_0-documentation.xsd

I am trying to apply some CSS to the above link.  It looks perfect in Firefox and Opera, but it is absolutely horrible in IE.  It seems the fonts are not being applied and no styles are being applied to namespace prefixed elements.  Any ideas?  Here is the CSS:

http://mailmarkup.org/hcl/hcl-stylesheet.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE is a jerk.

You need to change the CSS to include the namespace. Change for example

```
schema { ... }
```

to

```
xs\:schema { ... }
```

(the backslash is there to escape colon because it's a special character in CSS)

*Edit*: This has apparently the caveat that it doesn't work on the real webbrowsers. In this case, you need to add it to the class identifier.

```
schema, xs\:schema { ... }
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius and a savior.